# Redis client command error

Tags: c++, c, unix, redis, hiredis

I am using `hiredis`. `hiredis` has the api:

```
  void* redisCommand(redisContext *c, char *format, ...)
```

If the format is a c string contain '\0', the format is truncated. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the binary safe command:

```
redisCommand("set %b %b", key, keyLen, value, valueLen);
```

Answer (score 0):

C and C++ are different languages.

In C, a *string*, by definition, is a contiguous sequence of non-null characters followed by and including a null character terminator.  Anything else is not a string.

If you are using a function which only accepts a C string, nothing else is valid and that would be a design-decision and not a "bug" requiring a "fix".  If the source-code for **hiredis** is available to you, you might be able to gain additional insight by examining that source-code.